# PHP Code to Generate Routes Between Two Stations

Tags: php, mysql

I have two database tables;

```
tbl_Stations {station_id, name, address, contact, office_hours}

tbl_routes_fare {route_id, from_id, destination_id, fare_amount}
```

The *from_id* and *destination_id* both are foreign keys from *tbl_stations* indicating the source and destination of the route respectively.

My problem is, I have tried to come up with a PHP code that when once I key in more than one stations into the database from a form, it generates the routes and input them into the *tbl_routes_fare* automatically, i.e if the routes are A and B, the routes will be A -- B and B -- A, when I add a third station C, new routes are added which are A -- C, C -- A, B -- C and C -- B. The *route_id* is an auto-increment value while *fare_amount* has a default value of 0, which can be altered later after the routes have been created.

I need your assistance on this or pointing to a link that can assist me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your code so far is....?

Comment: If you have the algo in mind, and only need a lead, look into `stored procedures`, to write the algo in, and `triggers`, to trigger your stored procedure everytime a new entry is made in the `tbl_Stations` table.

Comment: @gaganshera, I think a trigger will work perfectly well here. Such that when the data is input in the stations table, the trigger generates routes.

Comment: @user2978051 If this helped you, shall I put it as an answer?

Comment: Hi, actually it gave me an idea of how to go about it but am still unable to write the code. I am new to triggers. Do you know how to go about it?